# Is assigning to String variable costly in terms of memory and time?

Tags: java, android, string, android-recyclerview

```
String timeStamp = currentCommentObjectObj.getTimeStamp();

holder.timeStamp.setText(timeStamp);
```

or

```
holder.timeStamp.setText(currentCommentObjectObj.getTimeStamp());
```

Which is better from a time and space optimisation perspective?

More information :-
   This code is inside onBindViewHolder of recycler view.

Comment: why do you care? Is this a bottleneck in your code? Probably not

Comment: If you don't plan on re-using `timeStamp` then go with the second example.

Comment: The second is a bit _clearer_ to me, since I don't have to worry about what else might use `timeStamp`. But as for memory and time, you definitely won't notice the difference between these two.

Comment: What is your evidence that these wind up being different in the compiled output?

Comment: @TimCastelijns If I have 100s of this kind of things?
This was just a representative.

Comment: @CommonsWare I dont know, question is also about that as well.

Comment: again why do you care? Is your app slow? Is this the cause? Probably not

Comment: I want to make the efficient one (if there is one) a general practice in my job.

Comment: To optimize your time it's better to not have one line long code since is difficult to read. In the example you mentioned are fine both implementations.

Comment: @easyjoin.net I meant not optimizing my time, I meant the application users time. :D

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat i understood that. But normally is more important to programing trying to optimize your time rather the cpu time. You have to optimize your code only when is need it. ;-)

Comment: @easyjoin.net It depends on the context though. :)
Yes agree...
"Premature optimisation is the root of all evil"
:D

Answer (score 2):

Although I prefer the second one, I believe that there is no difference. Because somewhere in the compilation steps the compiler optimizes your code and would recognize such discrepancies if any.

Please refer to http://www.noesispoint.com/jsp/scjp/SCJPch0.htm for more information.

Apparently first `javac` (the Java Compiler) compiles the code to JavaByteCode and then the Java Virtual Machine's compiler `JIT` optimizes and compiles the Byte code to the machines language.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the compiler/JVM behavior, this is an operation that should be essentially instantaneous.

On a machine level, the only possible difference between the two methods is

(a) saving a pointer to memory, then loading the pointer, or

(b) passing the pointer directly to the next method call.

The amount of time that is different between these two is so small that it essentially will never matter, for any Object. Even in a loop, Android UI code should not be executed enough times for this to ever possibly matter.